# Add an option to hide deleted answers when we reach 10k?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, 10k-tools, user-experience

Now that I have 10k rep, I see the deleted answers.  I'd rather not see them unless I ask to.

Is there a way to hide them?

Short of starting some bounties, that is.

Comment: I believe this was already asked elsewhere.. Can't find it though.

Comment: On Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content

Comment: See also [Hide deleted answers with certain characteristics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110535/hide-deleted-answers-with-certain-characteristics) on the Overmeta. Starting bounties is not such a bad idea, by the way ;)

Comment: @Roomba, IMHO it's not even annoying, deleted answers are always sorted last, so you can stop reading as soon as you see a purple background. *(Disclaimer: It looks like that color is often referred to as "red" on the SE network, but come on guys, it definitely looks more like purple to me. Maybe it's the alpha.)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Not if you sort by activity.

Comment: The duplicate closure direction here should be reversed. This is a far more direct request than Michael B's (and is older, to boot).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, please. There's a strange assumption that the more reputation you have, the more enthusiastic you are about participating in moderation. (For me the reverse is true).

I'm not sure what else to say, other than "Yes please", and some sort of impolite epithet.

Comment: Would always sorting them to the bottom, but adding sort-options for 10K users corresponding to the current active/oldest sort-order fulfill your aim? Or do you really need them completely gone?

Comment: Pushing them to the bottom would be a big improvement.

Comment: As someone who just hit 10k, I landed here searching for this very thing. as the top Google result. If you're annoyed by these, just block `stackoverflow.com##.answer.deleted-answer` with your Ad blocker. Problem solved.