# Removing deleted answers from view

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, sorting, 10k-tools

I recently gained access to [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

One of the privileges is viewing deleted posts. I understand why it's important for experienced users to have this feature. As stated in the description, users should:

> - Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community
>     and/or moderator team.
> - Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.

Sensible enough.

My question is about really old deleted answers. I've noticed that questions are cluttered with deleted answers dating back to at least 2009.

This clutter can be very distracting. Plus, it appears to be useless:

These answers have presumably been reviewed countless times over the years by users with enough rep – and they remain deleted.

I guess I'm not seeing the benefit of displaying old deleted answers, or understanding why they aren't permanently removed.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Remove deleted answers from view after one year, or
2. Provide a feature to hide deleted answers, or
3. First list the live answers. Then at the bottom (or the end, in multi-page), list the deleted answers. Give the live answers a dedicated sort tool. Now deleted answers are still available, but completely out of the way. (Thanks to @Deduplicator for the comment with this suggestion.)

---

*Side note...*

Before I broke 10K rep I was wondering why [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34199795/3597276) was giving away 500 rep in an easy bounty. His bounty notice said: *I hate mod tools and am getting close to 10K*.

Today I took a look at [his bounties offered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246568/william-jockusch?tab=bounties). He regularly goes out of his way to stay below 10K.

I think I understand why now. Although honestly, the mod tool issue isn't that big a deal to me. It's just a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: Having access to moderator tools means you will want to have the ability to see deleted content *whenever the need arises* for moderation purposes. For example, some users may have a history of plagiarism or other bad behavior dating back many years. This is why we never permanently delete anything after a certain amount of time since soft-deletion. I can totally get behind having a way to show/hide deleted answers, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an option to hide deleted answers when we reach 10k?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288803/add-an-option-to-hide-deleted-answers-when-we-reach-10k)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I looked for a duplicate but didn't find one. Thanks for that. And the user who authored that question is the same guy I referenced in my side note! LOL... That said, there is no useful answer in that question, so I wouldn't count this as a duplicate.

Comment: As mentioned, the duplicate referenced above is not very useful. I guess I was looking on the wrong SE site. There are better duplicates on Meta Stack Exchange: See [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132134/300177) & [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110535/300177).

Comment: I prefer your option #2.  I don't understand why it is in the interest of Stack Overflow to show me deleted answers when I don't want to see them.

Comment: It looks like deleted answers are pushed to the bottom when (but only when) sorting by votes. Consider [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?answertab=votes#tab-top), if you sort by votes, then [the deleted answers with a +1 score are below the answers with a 0 score](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b2R35.png). But that's not the case with other sorting methods. You (the OP) are probably aware of this, but I was not and thought I'd share for others reading this question.

Comment: Everybody saying "The deleted answers don't bother me, so they shouldn't bother you either" is wrong. I find them annoying and distracting, and I don't deserve to be punished for my >10K rep. FWIW, I made a Safari extension to hide them: https://github.com/kristopherjohnson/HideStackOverflowDeletedAnswers

Comment: Anyone noticed that deleted answer on this page? Hiding deleted answers would kill that subtle irony...

Comment: I just faced this issue [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552225/1997232) and then after 5 minutes I found this topic, which I already upvoted and nothing has changed... ><

Answer (score 27):

I think #3 is the best choice here. Until I started playing around with the sorting (an example being [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested in a now-deleted comment. Sort it by "active"), I assumed that this was always the case.

I don't think that deleted answers need their own sort criteria. But regardless of the criteria, they should always come last. By definition, they are of less worth than non-deleted answers.

Comment: I always sort by active, and wouldn't mind deleted answers all pushed to the bottom. I'm just accustomed to scrolling past them and don't think much of it anymore.

Comment: As someone who just hit 10k, I landed here via a Google search for how to solve this very thing. If you're annoyed by these, just block `stackoverflow.com##.answer.deleted-answer` with AdBlock Plus. I know that's not what the site owners would like folks to do, but I am either moderating or using the site - I shouldn't have to do both simultaneously.