# Reaction to several deprecated answers

Tags: discussion

A few days ago I spent about a day going in circles because most of the answers on SO for a specific problem were using deprecated methods, and the ones that were answering my question in an up-to-date manner were not so well written and not popular at all. Should I go now and place a comment on all of them stating that they are deprecated?

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Yup, that's certainly not a bad idea.

Comment: @Pekka Hello, can u show me how to write deprecated in the comments based on the so's standards? Should I just write deprecated in bold and the reason in regular letters?

Comment: I'd just form a natural sentence, without bolding and such.

Comment: See also [Implement a way to “deprecate” Answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314172/implement-a-way-to-deprecate-answers?rq=1)

Comment: Don't use text-type on SO.  Write out the full words.  *Hello, can you show me...*

Comment: and up vote the non deprecated answer.... if its good...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good question, old version-dependent answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) Editing the answer to include the version it was correct for is the way to go, since people are still using the old version.  I did this over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font. It took about 6mo for my (correct) answer to make it up to the second answer.

Comment: @cale_b, I saw your admonition to Cap, with its many upvotes, and am compelled to express a different opinion. Since Cap's meaning is clear, the question his or her first, and the supposed infraction contained only in a comment, I'd urge a more relaxed attitude, ideally exhibited by letting such things go unremarked. Short of that, a "please" or helpful citation of the rule against abbreviated words strike me as more in keeping with the welcoming attitude we all strive for as Stack Overflow users.

Comment: A newer development is *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The better solution is to write a complete answer with the new updated approach. That way you get a little bit of credit/recognition for your hard work and help others save that trouble in the future.

I would put in a quote box to make it stand out at the top of your answer.

> The existing answers are not valid anymore because they use deprecated
>   methods. This answer provides the correct solution as of this datetime.

Or something like that.

If there are a bunch of questions with the same deprecated answer, then you should either flag them as duplicates of a single question that has your now correct answer.

Self answered questions are encouraged as well for ["hard to find this on the internet"](https://xkcd.com/979/) type things.

Comment: Please don't use markup incorrectly because of the way it renders on a particular platform. Quote markup is for block quotations, not "highlighting". Other than that, this answer is spot-on, however.

Comment: Looks like highlighting to me -- however my friend using lynx says it looks exactly the same as everything else. Of course, only one of us can be right about what block quotes are.

Comment: Consider just starting your answer with "The answers suggesting to use _foo_ and _bar_ may work, but _foo_ and _bar_ are deprecated as of _version_ because they've been replaced by _baz_", optionally including links to the other answers but without any special markup. I find any answer that makes a big point of saying "other answers are not valid, but mine is correct" suspicious. Politely saying the other answers may have been good but are no longer the best is functionally equivalent, but I find the tone much more agreeable.

Comment: @JJ: look at the generated HTML.

Comment: avoid non-specific criticism. @JeffreyBosboom has suggested a better wording. There is a non-zero chance that OP does not understand existing answers. Pointing out what exactly OP thinks is wrong may help to improve either the answers or OP's understanding of the answers (or both).

Comment: To highlight the initial part of such an answer, I would suggest you use _italics for emphasis/highlight_ and then add a separator `---` (three scores) to create a line split and separate it from the actual answer. Quote format should be used for quoting and code format should be used for code.