# Warnings on past answers that use mysql_ functions

Tags: feature-request

With the deprecation of `mysql_` functions from PHP 7, I think it would be beneficial from the community to display generic warning messages on **past** answers using any `mysql_` functions.

An idea of the message could be:

> This answer used deprecated and removed (as of PHP 7) `mysql_` functions. If you use this code we recommend to update them to `mysqli_` or use PDO.

The idea is not related to people asking new questions, but more directed at people who take code from past questions and answers. I think tackling the source could be more beneficial, because not everyone who uses the code will be a registered member or post a question.

The idea would be to only show this message if a `mysql_` function is used in a code block within an answer, as to avoid any false positives.

Edit: For clarity, my question relates to past answers, not new questions.

Comment: 1) It is not deprecated anymore, it got completely removed 2) Looking at this question in a more abstract way it is about deprecated code/answers. [And this has already been discussed.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314172/3933332)

Comment: `mysql_` was deprecated for several years. I feel ashamed when I see how many users still use `mysql_` functionality. Now the time has come where they find their script not working...

Comment: Related: [Automatically warn against the use of mysql\_\* functions on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143379/260312)

Comment: @Rizier123 I'll edit my question to update wording that it has been removed. Could you also provide a link to past discussions of tackling this in a historic way, rather than on new questions only

Comment: @vaultah That topic is more directed at targeting new questions, not historic answers.

Comment: Some answers might involve saying "`myslq_` is obsolete", do this instead. An automated script marks such answers as obsolete might be bad.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I understand where you're coming from, but to do this for all past answers manually would be painstakingly time consuming.

Comment: True, perhaps limiting it to appearing in code blocks would be enough.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Oh, yes I see what you mean now. Yeah, only displaying the message if found within a code block in the answer would be best.

Comment: Beware being [accused of spamming if you decide to do something about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318885/fixing-answers-that-recommend-chmod-777).