# After a year or more, I should be able to remove my upvote of an answer

Tags: feature-request, voting

I'm looking at [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line).  In 2014, I upvoted the accepted answer, and at the time it was a reasonable way of handling the problem.

But now, that answer doesn't work on any Windows OS that's come out in the last 10 years.  It was barely the right answer then, but it's definitely the wrong answer today.

I should be able to remove my upvote.

[image]

You may also want to see [this related meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314172/implement-a-way-to-deprecate-answers/314179#314179), about deprecating answers that are no longer acceptable.  This would be a small workaround until that's figured out.

Comment: The question is still tagged windows server 2003, so the answer is no more wrong today than it was back then. Should there still be someone that needs to support this aged OS then these answers can still apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But now, that answer doesn't work on any Windows OS that's come out in the last 10 years.

You can edit the answer to point this out.

> I should be able to remove my upvote.

Once the answer has been edited you can remove your upvote.

Comment: This is the right answer. Regardless of the voting issue, the answer should be edited to notify people that it is no longer correct.

Comment: @NathanArthur It's not that it's no longer correct, but rather the answer should be edited to indicate what version(s) of the product it is valid for.  It's still a correct answer for anyone using those versions.

Comment: Ok.  I suppose this works.  Feels a little weird since his post clearly stated at the top that it was for Windows 2003.  But I added text that made it clear that it doesn't work for future OSes.

Comment: @RyanShillington Technically the post just said that a given 3rd party library solves the problem, with a link to download it, and it so happens that that 3rd party library has an OS version number in its name.   The point was that it didn't specifically indicate that that 3rd party library isn't usable by any other OS.  Since, apparently, people think that that wasn't clear, you can make that clear.  While it's fine to add in that information, it's not really appropriate to editorialize it by saying, "Skip this answer if you're using an operating system released in the last 10 years."

Comment: Oh.  Ok.  Would "Skip this answer if you're not using Windows 2003" have been better?

Comment: @RyanShillington You can see my edit.  I'd just try to focus on the facts.  Say that the answer works for Windows 2003 and doesn't work for windows 2008 and later.  That said if you'd written that last line I probably wouldn't have bothered editing it, but the original line just seems to be taking a bit of a quip at the author of the answer.

Comment: Yup.  Makes sense.  Thanks.