# Answer number also counts deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, design

When you can see the deleted posts, the answer number shows the total number of answers, including all deleted answers.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagick-imagemagick-php-extension-on-windows-7) shows:

[image]

But 9 out of these 15 answers are deleted, most of them are of such quality:

[image]

I fail to see the reason why the answer count takes deleted answers into account. It's not a good experience when you find there are 15 answers at first but finally realize that fewer than half are actually answer.

Comment: As a 10k user, is it possible to chose **not** to see the deleted answers? Or are they shown no matter what?

Comment: @yivi AFAIK, there is no way to disable.

Comment: That's bad. I wouldn't call this a _bug_ though. The number shown is correct. There are 15 visible answers for you.

Comment: @yivi Not sure. For me, if those were deleted as not-an-answer or very-low-quality, like most of them in that question, they shouldn't be called "answer".

Comment: As a <10k user, it only shows "6 Answers" for me. I agree with @yivi - there _are_ 15 answers visible to you and from a user design perspective, it would be weird claiming that there are only 6 where 15 are visible.

Comment: Then again, it could be a bug. Who am I to say otherwise? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: but they remain answers even if they are deleted, so I wouldn't call this a bug ... it's for sure bydesign and if you don't like it you can make it a feature request

Comment: So I changed it to feature-request.

Comment: Are deleted answers shifted to the bottom of the answers, or are they mixed in amongst the non-deleted ones?

Comment: Not so related, but I have a [ToC userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7994/9011) to display a summary of answers in the sidebar, which also indicates which ones are deleted, clicking on them will scroll to the post. (I mostly made this to navigate those questions with answers spanning multiple pages). Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/589wx.gif, suggestions welcome

Comment: @JamesWhiteley They are at bottom, but the total answer number is misleading, it make me think there are more information than it actually is.

Comment: If your FR is "please make it so the header doesn't count deleted answers", its value seems rather low, IMO. If it is "allow me to hide these answers", then that FR has already been made (quite probably more than once).

Comment: Related, from our [own meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313401/removing-deleted-answers-from-view). And in [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content), of course.

Comment: @yivi I don't think the value is that low, for popular questions with many spam answers, that number can be very misleading at the first glance.

Comment: I agree. The reason someone is deleting it, means it isn't an answer

Comment: Perhaps they could put something like: "15 answers (6 not deleted)" or "15 answers (9 deleted)"

Comment: When you have >= 10K rep then you do get to see dead people.  It is a moderation "privilege", you ought to check whether the question should be protected when it gets so many junk answers.  Easy to do, takes just one click.

Answer (score 5):

After [some modifications](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/commit/a46ac602fc618051415c4d8bbf541ffc87763a11), my existing [**Post Headers & Sidebar ToC**](https://stackapps.com/q/7994/9011) userscript will now:

- **toggle the display of deleted answers** on the question (not just the ToC list),
- **save this preference** (via localStorage) so it persists between page loads,
  [image]
- and will also **display the number of deleted answers**
  [image]

### [Source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/PostHeadersQuestionToc.user.js) ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/PostHeadersQuestionToc.user.js))