# How to prevent deleted answers from appearing?

Tags: support

I recently misunderstood a question and provided an incorrect answer. However, within seconds of posting, I realised the correct solution.

Rather than editing the same answer, I decided to write a new answer and delete the previous one. This was because it would have been very weird for anyone looking at the edit history (or so I think).

The problem now is that my deleted answer is always visible to me. Is there some way I can permanently delete it, or hide it from my view?

---

[Found this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313401/removing-deleted-answers-from-view), but my case is different as I do not have moderator privileges.

Comment: @yivi, Not really. I haven't reached 10k and right now I'm only looking to hide "my own" answer which was deleted.

Comment: It's the same thing. You have the privilege of seeing your own deleted posts, as 10k can see other users' deleted posts.

Comment: @yivi Oh yes, I agree. But it seems that there isn't any option to do so yet. Should this be reopened as a feature-request?

Comment: No, it should be closed as a duplicate of the existing feature request.

Comment: @yivi Done, voted to close :)

Comment: Side note: there is nothing wrong in completely rewriting the answer if it has no positive votes. If you really want to keep bad answer as separate one in deleted state - add some comment (inline in deleted answer) so anyone who sees it later (including you) know what is wrong and why it should *stay deleted*.

Comment: Side note to side note: you can temporarily delete an answer while you are rewriting it. This avoids confusing people with your bad answer, and halts any upvotes and downvotes.  ( Normal deleting really means "hide from normal users".  )